# $\phi(v)=(\pi(v),\exp_{\pi(v)}(v))$ is a local diffeo.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I try to understand the proof of the following statement:

For $p \in M$,the map $\phi:\Omega \to M \times M$ defined by
$$\phi(v)=(\pi(v),\exp_{\pi(v)}(v))$$
is a local diffeomorphism.

The proof is given as follow:

The idea is to use the inverse function theorem. Hence it suffices to show that the differential $\phi$ in $0 \in T_pM$ is invertible. Let $(U,\psi)$ be a local chart around $p$. The map $\phi: TU \cong U \times \Bbb R^n \to M \times M$ is given by $\phi(x,v)=(x,\exp_x(v))$. For $p$ fixed and $t$ small enough, we have $\phi(p,vt)=(p,c_v(t))$. Now I don't understand the next step:
$$\phi_*(\frac{\partial}{\partial v})=(0, \frac{\partial}{\partial v})$$
How do we get this? What does $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ mean?

Update: Is it correct to interpret $\phi_*$ in the following way: $\phi_*:T_p(U \times \Bbb R^n) \to T_{h(p)}(M \times M)$, $[v]\mapsto [\phi \circ v]$?

Comment: The tangent vector which is represented by the directional derivative in direction $v$. In your example, it coincides with $c_v^\prime(0)$

Comment: Could you please explain it a bit more? Sorry I am very new in this subject... I don't understand how I can plug one vector and get 0 and the identity..

Comment: If it is written $\phi_* (v) = (0,v)$ can you understand why?

Comment: Well sadly no, I think there is my problem

Comment: Is my update correct?

Comment: What are $\Omega$ and $\pi$?